# Passing an observable with async pipe to an input causes an infinite loop of calling http method and no value is returned

Tags: angular, typescript, http, asynchronous, observable

I have a table where there is a column that requires a value from an HTTP request for each record, so I used a method that returns an observable as follows:

```
getItem(obj): Observable<string> {
        return this.http.get('/someServiceurl').pipe(
          map(res => {
            var x = res.element
            return x;
          });
      }
```

In the table the row is as follows (where the input is of type string):

```
    <td>
        <component [input]="(getItem(obj) | async)">
        </component>
    </td>
```

What happens is that it goes into infinite HTTP calls even without passing the value to the component input, although the value is returned from the HTTP call.
So what causes that and is there another method to call an HTTP in a loop for each element in the table asynchronously.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the whole table structure:

```
<p-table [value]="mainList" 
            [totalRecords]="Count" [paginator]="true" [showCurrentPageReport]="true"
            currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries" [rows]="5">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>..........</th>
            <th>..........</th>
            <th>..........</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-obj>
        <tr>
            <td>{{obj.date}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.status}}</td>
            <td>
                <component [input]="(getItem(obj) | async)">
                </component>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Comment: what does the code look like in your `component` component? Could you post the whole table HTML structure?

Comment: @Andres2142 the code of the component is large, regarding the [input] it handles any changes occurs in it through the ngOnChange() method. I will add the table HTML structure

Comment: You shouldn’t do this: getItem(obj) in the template. Every change detection it will be called and you create a new observable and therefore a new call..

Comment: @MikeOne yes I understood you, but what can I do?

Comment: Just assign a variable to your observable and use that variable in your template. So like: public myData$ = this.http.get('/someServiceurl').pipe(
          map(res => {
            var x = res.element
            return x;
          });

Comment: @MikeOne but the observable and the value in it is different from one record to another in the table (it is a function of the table item) so it is not one value

Comment: That sounds like a mistake in design to be honest.. I assume you know what the table is made up from your component? The data needs to control other data, not the template. Does that make sense?

Comment: @MikeOne Actually I know this should be handled in the backend, but I don't have access to it so I am trying to handle this in the frontend

Comment: You can still do this in the frontend, but the logic needs to be in the component, not the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so yea, this is causing an infinite change detection loop. functions in template run on every change detection cycle, which causes a new observable to be constructed, which causes the async pipe to run, then output from the async pipe causes a change detection cycle. rinse, repeat.

pipe method works as that breaks the loop by ensuring the observable is only built when the input to it (`obj` in this case) changes. It's probably the more appropriate course if you will need to build this same observable in the same manner often, but may be a little heavy if you're only doing it here.

An alternative is to set the observable on the items in your table. something along the lines of.

```
// this is just a guess / example. i don't know how your mainList is actually built
this.mainList = this.service.fetchList().map(i => {
  i.item$ = this.getItem(i);
  return i;
})
```

then in template:

```
<component [input]="obj.item$ | async"></component>
```

this similarly ensures the observable on each item in the list is only built when the list itself is built.

Another alternative is to just handle the subscribing in the sub component, but maybe don't want to do that for other reasons.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is exactly what I did and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

That

```
<component [input]="(getItem(obj) | async)"></component>
```

looks like the culprit (let me guess, change detection strategy: default?). On every change detection cycle the expression `getItem(obj)` is evaluated, `http.get` gets called, requests goes out, and, I'm guessing, that triggers change, which triggers change detection, and here we go again.

One possible solution: from that

```
http.get('/someServiceurl').pipe(map(res => res.element))
```

make a pipe:

```
@Pipe({name: 'getItem'})
export class GetItemPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  transform(value: string): Observable<SomeInterface> {
    return this.http.get(value).pipe(map(res => res.element));
  }
}
```

and in the template:

```
<component [input]="obj | getItem | async"></component>
```

Comment: you're correct why this is happening, but i dont think the change detection strategy matters, a function into an async pipe is always going to cause an infinite loop since output from the async pipe causes a change detection cycle in default and onpush, and a change detection cycle always evaluates all functions in template.